# What Does It Mean When Cross Correlation Between Two Images Occur at Negative Coordinates

Tags: image-processing, matlab, cross-correlation

I am using Matlab *normxcorr2* to calculate the cross correlation between several images, something like what has been done here: [in MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html). There are some of the examples that I get negative values for *xoffSet* and *yoffSet*, but I am not sure what it means when these values are negative.

Another issue, is practical since I need to give these *xoffSet* and *yoffSet* values as an input to coordinates of rectangle in an image, but since these are negative, the function throws an error. I googled it but no success in finding something that can explain such thing. I was thinking of just putting zero instead of negative values, but I'm not sure if that's a right approach.

I would appreciate if someone can explain about the meaning of such negative values and how I can substitute such negative values with appropriate quantities.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  It sounds like the coordinates your call to `peak` is returning is in the padding area added by `normxcorr2`.  Are you sure you are giving the `yoffSet = ypeak-size(onion,1);` call the correct image (i.e. your `onion` patch image).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Basically, to find yoffSet, and xoffSet, I need to subtract the first and second dimensions of the template image (the image with the smaller size), respectively, from ypeak and xpeak. So, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the best match to template happens outside the image.

For instance, let's say your template is 5 by 5.
And you got answer which is -1, -1. It means the part of the image which best matches you image is centered at [-1, -1] and you only have part of it in your image.

This is really an extreme case.

P. S.
If you share your data (2 Images) we'll be able to assist more.

Comment: Thank you for your response Royi! Unfortunately, I cannot share my images. Can you clarify what you mean by outside the image? By image, do you mean the parent image for which we want to find the maximum correlation with a template? If so, how does it happen? And is there anyway to transform these negative values inside the image area?

Comment: Can you please add some clarifications to your answer based on my questions in the comment?